# c++ debugging doesn't start running the program immediately but restarting the debugger makes it work again

Tags: c++, gdb

I am running a C++ program through a debugger and I am probably missing something but this is the sequence of events

```
gdb bin/COL_sep
copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from bin/COl_sep...
(gdb) run arg1.txt
Starting program: /Users/morph/Code/bin/COL_sep arg1.txt
[New Thread 0x2403 of process 45643]
```

And then nothing happens forever.

but if I exit by pressing `CTRL+Z` and then do the exact same things again, the program runs
fine.

```
gdb bin/COL_sep
GNU gdb (GDB) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from bin/COL_sep...
(gdb) run arg1.txt
Starting program: /Users/morph/Code/bin/COL_sep arg1.txt
[New Thread 0x2803 of process 45665]
[New Thread 0x1b03 of process 45665]
warning: unhandled dyld version (16)
Problem Statistics: 
num  Nodes: 30
num  Arcs: 120
num  weights: 20
```

I am not sure why it doesn't run the first time.  Every time I recompile it never runs the first time. Can someone please let me know how to rectify this?

Comment: One explanation could be that your C++ code is doing something that invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (such as writing to an array out of bounds), which happens to behave normally under certain conditions, and unreliably under other conditions. That is the nature of undefined behavior. Therefore, it would be helpful if you could provide an [mre].

Comment: The codebase is unfortunately more than 4000 lines and uses some commercial libraries. I am not sure If I can produce an MRE. I started fiddling wire debugger way late into the process. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You may want to disable [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), which is probably possible in the linker settings (this is possible on the Microsoft Windows platform), as that may introduce extra randomness in the executation. That way, it may be more likely that the program will either always fail or always succeed. If you are lucky, it will always fail, and you will be able to debug the problem reliably.

Comment: You may also want to remove other sources of randomness. For example, if you are using a pseudo-random number generator (PRNG), then you should initialize it with a fixed seed instead of a random one. Also, if your program reacts to external input, then you should try to make this input fixed and not random. Also the order of the input should be fixed, not random. If your program is using multi-threading, though, it will be very hard to eliminate all randomness, because the kernel's scheduler will always be a source of randomness.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Thanks, There is no randomness in the program. It is a single threaded program and the surprising thing is, I wrote an std::cout  immediately after the main starts and even that is not getting written to the console.

Comment: Did you put an [`std::flush`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) or [`std::endl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) at the end of the `std::cout`?

Comment: This is what I have in my main ```int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    std::cout << "Started the Problem" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::flush;``` and the program just doesn't run.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218934/discussion-between-andreas-wenzel-and-morpheus).